# Broadcast transactions to specific miners?

Tags: blockchain, ether

Is it possible to broadcast transactions specific or a small number of miners?

I believe there is a concept of private transactions, as used to mitigate front running to rescue vulnerable funds for example.

Comment: No such option AFAIK. And it logically doesn't make any sense to have it either. It would ruin the most fundamental concepts of the blockchain, which is to achieve data-integrity (correctness) via consent (acknowledgement of that data) by a wide range of participants.

Comment: Ethermine, Flashbots

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to this article: https://www.google.com/amp/s/samczsun.com/escaping-the-dark-forest/amp/ (or if you're not, you should read it).

To summarize the article: white hat hackers broadcast a transaction only to a mining pool which promised not to broadcast it publicly. The pool's miners mine the transaction and it gets revealed to people outside the pool only when it's already mined.

So in theory there are no private transactions. But in reality it is a possibility if you have the right connections.

Note that the term "private" here means only that the transaction is not known by most miners - all of the transaction's data becomes public after it's mined and the block is published.

Comment: Very interesting, I was not aware of such strategies.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to broadcast transactions specific or a small number of miners?

Broadcast, no. Send your transaction via an endpoint to a backroom mining service, yes. (If you can find one and can afford it.)

From your question it sounds like you've read one or other of [Ethereum is a Dark Forest](https://medium.com/@danrobinson/ethereum-is-a-dark-forest-ecc5f0505dff), or its sequel, [Escaping the Dark Forest](https://samczsun.com/escaping-the-dark-forest/).

The crux of the answer to your question is: If you know a miner, or have suffient mining power yourself, you can "privately" mine a block containing your target transaction without the need of broadcasting the transaction to the mem pool. When you've successfully mined the block, you then broadcast the entire block to the network.

I'm sure if you offered certain large mining operators enough money they'd be more than willing to privately mine you a block containing your transaction...

Comment: Okay, Lauri beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nodes broadcast transactions to their peers, and within seconds the whole network knows about them. Furthermore the consensus algorithm needs the transactions to be validated and executed by the majority of the full-nodes before being added to the blockchain.

As goodvibration said in his comment, such feature of broadcasting transactions only to a restrictive number of nodes is nonsense in a public blockchain. Indeed, the specificity of the blockchain is to guarantee a *trustless* data transfer based on a broad consensus.

The concept of private transaction exists on Ethereum. It refers to the use of cryptographic techniques (called zero knowledge proofs) in order to hide some information such as the token amount or the recipient, without breaking the consensus rules. Such private transactions are currently at the prototype stage.